# Creating a function from a 2D array in MATLAB (For use in ode45)

Tags: function, matlab, interpolation

I am a first time MATLAB user. I have a 2d array of t vs f in MATLAB. This 2d array correponds to a function, say f(t). I am using ode45 to solve a set of differential equations and f(t) is one of the coefficients i.e. I have a set of equations of the form x'(t)=f(t)x(t) or variations thereof. How do I proceed?

I need a way to convert my array of t vs f into a function that can be used in the ode45 method. Presumably, the conversion will do some linear interpolation and give me the equation of the best fit curve.

Or if there is another approach, I'm all ears!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example with passing function as a parameter to right hand side of the ODE. Create files in the same directory and run main

**main.m**

```matlab
t = 0:0.2:10; f = sin(t);
fun = @(xc) interp1(t, f, xc);

x0=0.5
% solve diff(x, t)=sin(t)  
% pass function as parameter                           
[tsol, xsol] = ode45(@(t, x) diff_rhs(t, x, fun),[0.0 8.0], 0.5);

% we solve equation dx/dt = sin(x), x(0)=x0
% exact solution is x(t) = - cos(t) + x(0) + 1
plot(tsol, xsol, 'x');
hold on
plot(tsol, -cos(tsol) + x0 + 1, '-');
legend('numerical', 'exact');
```

**diff_rhs.m**

```matlab
function dx = diff_rhs(t, x, fun)
  dx = fun(t);
end
```

References in the documentation: [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) and [anonymous Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It works but if I try and add fun(t) in ode45, it has a problem. It says Undefined function 'fun' for input arguments of type 'double'. 

I want to make it a global function somehow. For isntance, if I put sin(t) in ode45, it has no trouble. Can I get fun(t) to work in the same way? Thank you

Comment: Please try ode45(@(t, x) fun(x),[1.0 8.0], [0.5]);

Comment: Sorry, can I clarify your syntax? I'm using a general form

[t,x]=ode45('filename', tspan, x_zeros, options).

filename is where the differential equations are and those equations have fun(t) as the coefficients. Where should I add in @(t, x) fun(x),[1.0 8.0], [0.5] and what are those numbers? Thank you for your help! Appreciate it very much :)

Comment: The numbers are arbitrary.